# javascript var not correctly passed to backing bean

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, ajax4jsf

I have this piece of code that fails to work. I have `fieldToStore` defined. I can alert it and I can see its value in firebug console, but when it is passed to myBean it is always undefined in case of a String value or false in case it's boolean. 
Any ideas?

```
<a4j:commandButton id="bt1" action="#{myBean.doSomething}" onclick="fieldToStore=false;saveFieldState();">
</a4j:commandButton>        
<a4j:jsFunction name="saveFieldState" action="#{myBean.dummyAction}" />
   <a4j:actionparam name="fieldToStore" assignTo="#{myBean.fieldToStore}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

My expectation is that after i click on bt1 the value of myBean.fieldToStore is false, as per the javascript var fieldToStore.

Comment: Could you please post your code so that we can understand the problem ?

Comment: i'm trying to but it doesn't show :(

Comment: you need to put the code on a new line, and four spaces before each line.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined? Is the value of field 'fieldToStore' is 'undefined' or 'fieldToStore' is null/blank?

Comment: In case i'm assigning fieldToStore with String values it will pass the value "undefined". In case i'm assigning it with boolean values, it will always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... the problem was on the way i was calling the jsFunction on the event onclick:

```
onclick="fieldToStore=false;saveFieldState();
```

it should be:

```
onclick="fieldToStore=false;saveFieldState(fieldToStore);
```

The example on richfaces documentation is misleading:

```
<body onload="callScript()">
  <h:form>
         ...
        <a4j:jsFunction name="callScript" data="#{bean.someProperty1}" reRender="someComponent" oncomplete="myScript(data.subProperty1, data.subProperty2)">
              <a4j:actionparam name="param_name" assignTo="#{bean.someProperty2}"/>
        </a4j:jsFunction>
        ...
  </h:form>
  ...
</body>
```

Imo it should be onload="callScript(param_name)".

Answer (score 2):

You are using `<a4j:actionParam>`, that is [a combination of f:param and f:actionListener](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9781430210559/more-a4j-tags-concepts-and-features/using_la4j_colon_actionparamg) that assigns its `value` attribute to the property in `assignTo`.

You want to use `<a4j:param>` instead. See this [example in the official docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#exam-Component_Reference-a4jjsFunction-a4jjsFunction_example)

Comment: i've left my working tool at work because i was going nuts :) i will try that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that is only supported in richfaces 4.x and we're currently using 3.3.x.

Comment: Oh! Well, in this case you may try to use an `f:param` instead.

Comment: I think i'm doing everything according to the guidelines for 3.3.3 version: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html

Comment: Note that the onclick execution of `a4j:commandButton` is not synchronous with the execution of the `a4j:jsFunction`. If you are testing it on the `myBean.doSomething` method, it's very possible it to be undefined then. Could this be the case?